# Creating a diagram

Tags: plotting

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to create a diagram akin to this:

[image: diagram]

Basically, I have two figures, and I want to create a diagram where I have the two figures side by side and an arrow (denoting a morphism) connecting the two.

Comment: Yes, use Libre office draw. Why do you want to do this with *mma*?

Comment: truth be told because it's what i typically use, but there's no reason to not use something more practical! thanks for the rec

Comment: You could use, `Graphics[Arrow[]]` etc of course, it's a hassle though, especially if it becomes more than just a few object.

Comment: You could take a shot at it with the drawing tools... (menu Graphics > Drawing Tools).

Comment: `Arrow` with `Arrowheads` to be put between `Graphics/Plot` etc. in a `Grid` or `GraphicsGrid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspiring by an old question I asked, here is a possible way to encode your graph

```
ClearAll[esF]
esF[setback_: .2, 
   as_: .1] := {Arrowheads[as], 
    Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 0.5}][##], 
     setback]} &;
tor = Magnify[
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
     Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False], .35];
el = Magnify[Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, {.5, .25}]}], .35];
sq1 = Magnify[
   Graphics[{LightBlue, Thick, 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.015, 0.015}]}], .25];
sq2 = Magnify[
   Graphics[{LightRed, Thick, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.4, .5}]}], .35];
g0 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 4}, 
   EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Style["f", FontSize -> 16], 
     2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Style["ψ", FontSize -> 16], 
     3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 
      Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), \(-1\)]\)", 
       FontSize -> 16], 
     3 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> 
      Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ°f°ϕ\),\
 \(-1\)]\)", FontSize -> 16], 
     4 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 
      Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(-1\)]\)", 
       FontSize -> 16], 
     1 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> Style["ϕ", FontSize -> 16]}, 
   VertexLabels -> { 1 -> Placed[el, Center], 
     2 -> Placed[tor, Center], 3 -> Placed[sq1, Center], 
     4 -> Placed[sq2, Center]}, VertexShape -> 0.1];
Show[SetProperty[g0, EdgeShapeFunction -> esF[]], 
 Graphics[Text["M", {0, 1}]], Graphics[Text["N", {1, 1}]], 
 Graphics[Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(m\)]\)", {0, 0}]], 
 Graphics[Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(n\)]\)", {1, 0.1}]]]
```

Here is the result.

[image]

It is not completely satisfacing. First, I dont know how to oblige MA to put the vertices where we think they must be. Second, I dont know how to cope with the negative  curvature of the two horizontal arrows. Third, I have not found an other symbol for composition than [Degree]. Fourth, it would be nice eather to have an opaque box in the background of the text and perhaps an offset. To do this place blancks between cotes and letters before or after according to what you need.

You can finetune the position of $R^n$ inside the torus by increasing it a little and moving $ R^n$ to the right place. And, finally, you can change the fonts.

Last but not least,  such a composition is recurrent. It would be nice to be able to do it easily in MA. Latex + Pstricks is far better to do such graphics.

25//11/16

Finally, I have found the way to have, according to the question the perfect graph

```
ClearAll[esF]
esF[setback_: .2, 
   as_: .05] := {Arrowheads[as], 
    Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 0.5}][##], 
     setback]} &;  
tor = Magnify[
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
     Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False], .55];
el = Magnify[Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, {.5, .25}]}], .35];
sq1 = Magnify[
   Graphics[{LightBlue, Thick, 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.015, 0.015}]}], .25];
sq2 = Magnify[
   Graphics[{LightRed, Thick, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.4, .5}]}], .35];
g0 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 4}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
   EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Style["f", FontSize -> 16], 
     2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> 
      Style["ψ", FontSize -> 16, Background -> White], 
     3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 
      Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), \(-1\)]\)", 
       FontSize -> 16, Background -> White], 
     3 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> 
      Style[
       "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ∘f∘\
ϕ\), \(-1\)]\)", FontSize -> 16], 
     4 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 
      Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(-1\)]\)", 
       FontSize -> 16, Background -> White], 
     1 \[DirectedEdge] 4 -> 
      Style["ϕ", FontSize -> 16, Background -> White]}, 
   VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed[el, Center], 2 -> Placed[tor, Center],
      3 -> Placed[sq1, Center], 4 -> Placed[sq2, Center]}, 
   VertexShape -> 0.1];
Show[SetProperty[g0, EdgeShapeFunction -> esF[]], 
 Graphics[Text["M", {0, 1}]], Graphics[Text["N", {1.015, 1.015}]], 
 Graphics[Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(m\)]\)", {0, 0}]],
 Graphics[
  Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(n\)]\)", {1.009, 0.009}]]]
```

Here is the result

[image]

Yes one can decide where will be the vertices --- VertexCoordinates --- and the composition character is [EmptyCircle]

Comment: these are fantastic, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This sort of diagram can be made with `GraphPlot`. Here is a simple example, with "two figures side by side and an arrow (denoting a morphism) connecting the two".

One of figures is circle and the other a torus. The following is a function to draw the torus.

```
Options[torusUVPlot] =
  {BoundaryStyle -> Thin, PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes"}};
torusUVPlot[a_Real /; a > 0., r_Real /; r > 0., opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {(a + r Cos[u]) Cos[v], (a + r Cos[u]) Sin[v], Sin[u]},
    {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, 2 π},
    BoxRatios -> {a + r, a + r, r},
    Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts, Options[torusUVPlot]}, Options[ParametricPlot3D]]]
```

This makes it easy to refer the items at the vertices of the graph. I used an association to avoid order dependence.

```
items = 
  <|
    1 -> Graphics[{Thickness[.05], Circle[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
    2 -> torusUVPlot[1., .5, 
           ColorFunction -> (White &), Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> Tiny]
   |>
```

Drawing the diagram.

```
GraphPlot[
  {1 -> 2},
  DirectedEdges -> True,
  VertexCoordinateRules -> {1 -> {0, 0}, 2 -> {2, 0}},
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[items[#2], #1] &),
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> 
    ({Arrow[#1, .5], 
     Text[Style["f", 24, "TI", Background -> White], {0, .13} + Plus @@ #1/2]} &)]
```

[image: graph]