# How can I draw a block diagram of a certain kind?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to draw the diagram shown in the image shown below. I want to use Mathematica's `Graph` tool.

[image]

I evaluated

```
Graph[
  {6 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
  VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.1, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeStyle -> Black]
```

and the result was

[image]

What can I do to make Mathematica produce a graph that looks like the one that I want?

Comment: This isn't a "do your homework" website. Please show us what you've tried and where you've run into problems.

Comment: when I draw this in mathematica become as

Comment: I want to be like drawing the picture first!! this is my problem??

Comment: "when I draw this in mathematica" - what did *you* input into *Mathematica* to do this? Tell us here, and we can start from there.

Comment: Graph[{6 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
 VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> 0.1, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of `VertexStyle`, `VertexLabels`, `VertexFunction` etc?

Comment: If you want to control the layout you need to specify `VertexCoordinates"

Comment: You might find this useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2715/2079

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a specific question, the OP is simply asking others to supply his code.

Comment: You can start from http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131587/creating-a-diagram/131646#131646

Comment: Look into `VertexCoordinates` as george2079 said, or try `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be satisfacing ?

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 
  5 -> 7, 6 -> 7}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1.1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 2}, {2, 
    0}, {3, 1}},
 VertexShape -> Graphics[{LightGreen, Rectangle[{10, 10}]}], 
 VertexSize -> .2,
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["A", Center], 2 -> Placed["B", Center], 
   3 -> Placed["C", Center], 4 -> Placed["D", Center], 
   5 -> Placed["E", Center], 6 -> Placed["F", Center], 
   7 -> Placed["G", Center]},
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[{{.03, 1}}], 
     Arrow[#1, {.07 #2[[1]], .06 #2[[2]]}]} &)]
```